# Getting "invalid_token" and "unauthorized" for an security-excluded endpoint

Tags: spring, spring-security

I am ignoring my `/users` endpoint, which is where user registration data is being sent, like this:

```
@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    web.ignoring().antMatchers(
            "/users"
    );
}
```

*Interestingly*, the registration works. But if I register a duplicate user, which causes a constraint violation exception, the client will receive:

```
{
  "error": "invalid_token",
  "error_description": "Access token expired: eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1N .."
}
```

or sometimes

```
{
  "error": "unauthorized",
  "error_description": "Full authentication is required to access this resource"
}
```

I don't understand why this is happening. I have additional configuration code for OAuth2:

```
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
public class ResourceServer extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .requestMatchers().antMatchers("/**")
            .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest()
                .access("#oauth2.hasScope('write')");
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources) throws Exception {
        resources.resourceId(resourceIds);
    }

}
```

but I do not know if this is related to the issue.

How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of ignoring the endpoint allow it for all:

```
@Override
public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .requestMatchers().antMatchers("/**")
        .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/users").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().access("#oauth2.hasScope('write')");
}
```

The matchers are considered in the order they are declared, so it will check the `/users` matcher before `.anyRequest().access`.